# Background Image for Android App

Tags: java, android

I am an amateur android programmer and I am trying to stylize my app. I found a picture from the internet, here is the [link](https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1734009318/NWHS_JAG.jpg). I want to set that as my background on the application. I would I do so. I really don't understand the concept of @drawable/background, how does it work, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your picture into `res/drawable` folder. Then in your Layout file (`layout/main.xml`) high problably for your default project add this image view

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scale_type="center_crop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/your_picture_name"/>
```

BUT DON'T ADD YOUR PICTURE'S FILE EXTENTION. ONLY FILE NAME. FOR
 EXAMPLE IF YOUR PICTURE FULL NAME BEATIFULL_CAR`.JPG` ONLY ADD
 BEATIFULL_CAR

Comment: I see multiple drawable folders. One is located in the res and in bin>res

Comment: @user1842633 use **res/drawable**

Comment: I tried to add the file but it gave me this: [2013-03-06 14:24:03 - MyApp] res\drawable-hdpi\NWHS_JAG.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Comment: I think you tried **"\"** between paths and file names but it must be **"/"**

Comment: what do you mean. I just copied and pasted into the project from my pictures

Comment: as you can see from my code part there is a line **android:src="@drawable/your_picture_name"** after you copy/paste your picture you must reference to them with this line

Comment: <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scale_type="center_crop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/NWHS_JAG"/>

Comment: try to change your image's name simply to xyz. Then copy your image to all drawable folders drawable-hdpi,drawble-ldpi,drawble-mdpi,drawble-xdpi

Answer (score 0):

1. Drawable is a resource folder in your Android Project where you can past different data.
2. If you want to use any image as a background copy/past it in the Drawable folder and 
   use the attribute `android:background="@drawable/your_image_name"` in your layout_main.xml
   as

   `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/your_picture_name"
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

Thats it.

Your can know more about Drawable at this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)